# JButton with text below the icon

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

In Java Swing I would like to create a JButton which contains an image(icon) and some text. In few words a JButton(text,icon). 
I would like the text to be displayed below the image, and not beside, as in normal JButton layout. Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the method setVerticalTextPosition in [AstractButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setVerticalTextPosition-int-) using the constant 
`SwingConstants.BOTTOM`.